# Angular 2 vs Polymer

Tags: angular, polymer, web-component

I am working on a visualization project that requires to create chart components that can be integrated with multiple other projects to fulfill their visualization needs.Basically outcome of my project would be a JavaScript library that can be imported anywhere using script tags . I am confused between Angular 2 vs Web Components offering for creating these reusable chart components.These components should act as wrapper to D3.js chart generation code and can be readily used.

Comment: That depends on your concrete requirements. This is a primarily opinion based question and not a good fit for StackOverflow and should better be asked in other channels.

Comment: Neither one is really good for embedding in projects built with the other. Your best bet is probably a raw Javascript library. After all, that's what d3 does…

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks for valuable advice.Could you please help me out which other channels are suitable for these kind of questions?

Comment: https://gitter.im/angular/angular, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/angular, Polymer has a Slack channel, and probably others

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer concrete requirements is to deliver a package of HTML files that will contain set of charts created using D3.js .This package will be a sort of offline package that can be opened up on a browser .Source of data will be a JSON structure within the package.Need for re-usability arises when you start integrating the javascript library written in d3 with variety of projects . Component architecture helps to design a layer on top of this javascript library i.e. project using this library can write a tag <xyz-heatmap-chart></xyz-heatmap-chart>

Comment: @DanielLyons  ..Please see the requirements that I have posted above and let me know if you have some valuable to share.Thanks for your time.

Comment: extremely sorry to trouble you guys but this is really urgent..could you please actively give me some direction for this design question.

Comment: what does your Magic Quadrant recommend?

Comment: @Supersharp let me know your ideas and advice...will take everything into consideration before reaching any conclusion...thanks...

Comment: I think you should use light, vanilla, custom elements: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/customelements